# Bug when combining boolean search operators with tags containing plus signs

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

The site search allows to use tags as well as boolean operators, e.g. one can search for C++ and C# questions by entering `[c++] or [c#]`. The resulting URL is [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20or%20c%23`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20or%20c%23).

The search still works upon initially submitting the search phrase. Likewise, refreshing a page using the browser renders the expected result. Reloading the page using the *"newest"*, *"featured"*, etc. tabs, however, drops the plus signs. In my previous example (`[c++] or [c#]`) the submitted search turns into `[c] or [c#]`. The URL for the *"newest"* tab is [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b+or+c%23?sort=newest&pageSize=15`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b+or+c%23?sort=newest&pageSize=15). The other tabs are similar.

I have verified this using both Chrome as well as Edge. Can anyone else reproduce the issue, or is this a peculiarity of my system's configuration (e.g. locale settings)?

Comment: I reproduced this on Chrome/Win10 and Firefox so it is not your locale setting or system configuration.

Comment: I reproduced this as well

Comment: Hyphens also cause problems. `[c++-cli] or [c#]` becomes `[c] not [cli] or  [c#]`

Comment: @Turnip: I noticed the same, although I believe that hyphens aren't part of the issue. It's just what's left to parse, after the plus signs were dropped, or otherwise mangled, by the code generating the tab links.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. I can't reproduce without  `c++` in the the tag.

Comment: Windows 7 Google Chrome also has this bug.

Comment: Oh... You don't even have to anything complicated by yourself. Just go to the "Tags" page, find the `b+-tree` tag and click on it. Then the result page will show `[b] -[tree]`.

Comment: @MrLister: So that looks like a more pervasive bug in the link generation code then. And the only reason to change code is to fix a bug or to prepare/implement a new feature. At any rate, I'd hope to see this bug acknowledged and solved, in due time. So far this hasn't triggered any official feedback.

Comment: This will be my fault; I've been overhauling that code as part of a new feature - I obviously missed a key scenario. It will be rectified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should now be fixed; sorry about that.  Any more problems like this: probably best to just yell at me by default.

Comment: So, it wasn't Nick, huh. That's a surprise.

Comment: @braiam to be honest, anything tag related is usually me

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgement. A bit more detail would be helpful, though, so that we know, whether any particular observable behavior is/was part of this bug. I'd also like to understand, why a core component (link generation) made it to live servers, without any tests failing.