# Selecting C++ as related tag tries to search for tags merged together, or C

Tags: support, bug, search

When selecting a related tags after you've already selected [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) the search tries to search for the tags concatenated.

To reproduce:

1. Search for [questions tagged C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)
2. Pick a related tag, for example, [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c). We're now redirected to look at the [non-existent, but palindromic tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b+c) [c+++c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%2bc).

This doesn't appear to occur with other tags, like [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) or even [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23). For example, selecting [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) then [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) properly searches for [javascript + jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+jquery).

If [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) is selected as the second tag instead, it's replaced with [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c). To reproduce:

1. Search for a related tag to [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), for example [questions tagged qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt)
2. Pick [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) in the related tags, and notice you're now searching for [qt + c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt+c%2b%2b)

Comment: Related to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362508/72178.

Comment: Is `c+++c` invoking [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/949433/2564301)?

Comment: This question is most definitely not an exact duplicate of [this] question. It may report a different observable behavior of the same bug. But since none of the questions have received any type of official feedback, we don't even know that. So either re-open this question or give us a reason to close it as a duplicate.