# Is it something wrong with my profile page?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

When I click [my profile on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447156/soner-g%C3%B6n%C3%BCl), it redirects to

https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/447156/soner-g%C3%B6n%C3%BCl

and shown as;

[image]

I have no problem to view other users profile page.

I'm using Google Chrome 69.0.3497.100 x64 as a browser.

Comment: Works for me, same setup. My own profile works as well. Do you have a developer story?

Comment: Soner's developer story is what breaks for me, not his main profile.

Comment: Yeah what @VinkoVrsalovic said. It seems to be the developer story.

Comment: @rene Yeah, I have. That seems broken to me as well.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374804/walls-of-text-distort-user-profiles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fix for this rolling out in build rev `2018.10.2.31779`.

Comment: It seems that we are on `2018.10.2.31780` now and the developer story of the OP is still broken.

Comment: @Filnor I can access OP's profile without error. Maybe you have a cache issue ? (always blame cache)

Comment: I saw a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2524486/chetan-ansel) with [weird profile page](https://imgur.com/a/HVTvqGN) I wonder if this is related while other profiles looks fine. I am using Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: What caused the issue?

Comment: Why do these things make it into production in the first place? I mean, it's not the first time [an issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362508/1889329) that should immediately fail testing gets through. Is there no place for QA on this Q&A site? Have you just lost it over striving to be more agile than anyone else in this galaxy?

Comment: @Pac0 The profile always worked for me, but the developer story was still broken. But it was fixed in the meantime.

Comment: @Enzokie I had a temporary repro of that on IE 11, but not Chrome, Firefox or Edge (all latest stable).

Comment: @IInspectable Or at least to A/B testing while informing user about that.

Comment: @Filnor thanks for the input btw that's odd, ok right now I will just leave it to the devs.

Comment: @IInspectable In my experience in web dev- if there is pressure to meet a deadline fixes will be pushed out even if not fully tested for the sake of meeting arbitrary deadlines. In any case- I don't think its that unreasonable that SO will have bugs from time to time. The developers are human after all :)

Comment: @chevybow even linkedin does not break so badly, so SO has lower standards than linkedin now? next step = expertsexchange?

Comment: @IInspectable we're all testers. Now stop complaining and get back to work to find those bugs ... ;)